# Checking my answer on if this is a linear tranformation or not.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following function linear?

$T: R^2 \Rightarrow R$ such that $T(v_1,v_2) = v_1 -v_2 + 5$

**My solution:**

Let $v_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ and let $v_2 = (x_2,y_2)$

$T(\alpha v_1) = T(\alpha(x_1,y_1))$ = $T(\alpha x_1, \alpha y_1)$ = $\alpha(x_1-y_1) + 5$

$\alpha(T(v_1)) = \alpha (x_1-y_1+5)$

Therefore, $T(\alpha v_1) \neq \alpha(T(v_1)$ and thus nonlinear.

Not sure if I did this correctly, could you please advise if not..thank you!
And if I did do it correctly, is there a simpler, more intuitive way of solving?

Comment: Two comments: (1) You are using very confusing notation. In the definition of $T$ you have $v_1,v_2$ which are scalars but moments later they are elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$! (2) Your proof is along the correct lines, but you have not completed it. To show that $T(\alpha v_1) \neq \alpha T(v_1)$ you need to give a specific value to demonstrate that they are not equal. The zero vector is often a good choice, for example $T(2\cdot 0) = 5$ but $2 T(0) = 10$.

Comment: Note that if $T$ was linear, we must have $T(0) = 0$. Since $T(0) = 5$ is cannot be linear.

Comment: $T(\alpha v_1)=\alpha T(v_1)$ when $\alpha=1,$ but for linearity we'd need so for all $\alpha$